# Undo and redo on struct arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, undo-redo

Hi so I am trying to implement an undo-redo function in my Uni assignment. I have to do the "store the array" implementation but it doesn't work right. My Repository struct has a field that keeps the index of the last element, so after adding something it will be 0. Well after it goes through the undo, it becomes some large negative number. This is my source code:
'''

```
#include"UndoRedo.h"
#include<stdlib.h>

Undo* createUndo(Repo* repo) {
    Undo* undo = (Undo*)malloc(sizeof(Undo));
    undo->undo = (Repo*)malloc(sizeof(Repo) * 10);
    undo->availableUndos = 0;
    undo->undoSlots = 10;
    return undo;
}
Redo* createRedo(Repo* repo) {
    Redo* redo = (Redo*)malloc(sizeof(Redo));
    redo->redo = (Repo*)malloc(sizeof(Repo) * 10);
    redo->availableRedos = 0;
    redo->redoSlots = 10;
    return redo;
}
void addUndo(Repo* repo, Undo* undo) {
    if (undo->undoSlots < undo->availableUndos + 1) {
        growUndo(undo);
        undo->availableUndos += 1;
        undo->undo[undo->availableUndos] = *repo;
    }
}
void destroyUndoAndRedo(Redo* redo, Undo* undo) {
    free(undo->undo);
    free(undo);
    free(redo->redo);
    free(redo);
}
void addRedo(Undo* undo, Redo* redo) {
    if (redo->redoSlots < redo->availableRedos + 1) {
        growRedo(redo);
        redo->availableRedos += 1;

    }
}
int undo(Redo* redo, Repo* repo, Undo* undo) {
    addRedo(undo, redo);
    //printf("%d", repo->indexOfTheLastItem);
    *repo = undo->undo[undo->availableUndos];
    //printf("%d", repo->indexOfTheLastItem);
    undo->availableUndos--;

}
int redo(Repo* repo, Redo* redo, Undo* undo) {
    addUndo(repo, undo);
    *repo = redo->redo[redo->availableRedos-1];
    redo->availableRedos--;

}
void growRedo(Redo* redo) {
    redo->redoSlots *= 2;
    redo->redo = realloc(redo->redo, sizeof(Repo) * redo->redoSlots);
}
void growUndo(Undo* undo) {
    undo->undoSlots *= 2;
    undo->undo = realloc(undo->undo, sizeof(Repo) * undo->undoSlots);
}
```

'''

And here is how the undo and redo are created:
'''

```
#include"Repo.h"
typedef struct {
    Repo* undo;
    int undoSlots;
    int availableUndos;
}Undo;

typedef struct {
    Repo* redo;
    int redoSlots;
    int availableRedos;
}Redo;
```

'''

Also the Repo looks like this:
'''

```
typedef struct {
    Item* items;
    int allocatedSlots;
    int indexOfTheLastItem;
}Repo;

Repo* initRepo() {

    Repo* repo = (Repo *)malloc(sizeof(Repo));
    repo->items = (Item *)malloc(sizeof(Item) * 5);// Init the items array with 5 slots
    repo->allocatedSlots = 5;
    repo->indexOfTheLastItem = -1;
    return repo;
}
```

'''
I've checked and they get allocated just fine. I just don't know what is going on because after the Repo goes through the undo, I cannot access values of it(read access violation). Thanks for any effort!

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). `growRedo(Redo* redo)`, etc.. allocate storage within -- the return type should not be `void` you must provide a meaningful return that can indicate success/failure of the allocation. (and you must ***check the return***...)

Answer (score 2):

In `addUndo`, if there is *already* space for the next element, you do *not* store it [you only store when you *grow* it].

And, you're storing one beyond where you need to (i.e. you should increment the available count *after* you store).

You probably want:

```
void
addUndo(Repo *repo, Undo *undo)
{

    if (undo->undoSlots < undo->availableUndos + 1)
        growUndo(undo);

    undo->undo[undo->availableUndos] = *repo;

    undo->availableUndos += 1;
}
```

Likewise for `addRedo` ...

Comment: Yeah but I've tested for only one element added(I start with 10 slots), so that is deffinitely not the issue here.

Comment: You should post your _entire_ program so that people can download, build, and run/test it [and test the solution before answering]. As it is, there could be other issues in code you _think_ is okay that you didn't post.

Comment: **No**, it _definitely is_ the issue. In `createUndo`, you set available count to zero and `undoSlots` to 10. So, the very _first_ call to `addUndo` will assume you have space (i.e. the `if` is _false_), so the function will fail as I've already mentioned in my answer.